# C# byte arrays - signed and unsigned dilemma

Tags: c#, byte

I start with a signed byte array and convert to unsigned.. so is the printed result correct?

```
byte[] unsigned = new byte[] {10,100,120,180,200,220,240};
sbyte[] signed = Utils.toSignedByteArray(unsigned);
```

And the print (I just append them with a StringBuilder):

signed: [10,100,120,-76,-56,-36,-16] 
unsigned : [10,100,120,180,200,220,240]

where:

```
public static sbyte[] toSignedByteArray(byte[] unsigned){
    sbyte[] signed = new sbyte[unsigned.Length];
    Buffer.BlockCopy(unsigned, 0, signed, 0, unsigned.Length);
    return signed;
}
```

If I change to this I get the same result.

```
sbyte[] signed = (sbyte[])(Array)unsigned;
```

Shouldn't -128 (signed) become 0, -118 become 10, and so on.. and not 10 (signed) = 10 (unsigned)!?

Because 
sbyte    -128 to 127 
byte    0 to 255

So??

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Signed integers are represented in the [Two's complement system](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Two%27s_complement).

*Examples:*

```
Bits        Unsigned     2's complement
            value        value

00000000    0            0
00000001    1            1
00000010    2            2
01111110    126          126
01111111    127          127
10000000    128          −128
10000001    129          −127
10000010    130          −126
11111110    254          −2
11111111    255          −1
```