# Is the return of Utilities.ComputeDigest() an array of bytes?

Tags: javascript, arrays, google-apps-script

I am running Utilities.ComputeDigest() function (Google App Script) which returns byte[] which I think is byte array.

When I run a test using the debugger, it says that the array elements are numbers. (See below)

[My screenshot](https://i.stack.imgur.com/WcEy1.png)

Is this indeed a byte array?

Comment: Byte array is just a number array with numbers ranging from -128 to 128

Comment: @TheMaster - If I use `element[i] = parseInt(input, 16);` statement in the loop and inject `53d873`, I would get [83,216,115].

Does it mean that the array [83,216,115].is not byte array, because the value (216) is not between -128 and 128?

Comment: See [this](https://stackoverflow.com/a/20639942/) and [this](https://stackoverflow.com/q/10474186/) Byte arrays in apps script are signed.